# How to implement location awareness

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, scripts

Is there any way I can make my laptop running kubuntu a bit more intelligent as to where it is?

I imagine this being done by detecting what wifi connections are around, or even just what wifi/wired network it's connected to and then being able to start/stop programs, run scripts etc. But really I don't mind how it's done.

Is there any way (program / script) I can implement this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely! You will be happy to know that if you write a KDE Plasmoid, you have access to the Geolocation API in HTML5, which provides precisely the data you want without you having to worry about how it is implemented.

- [Getting started with Plasmoid development](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Plasma/Web/GettingStarted)
- [Simple demo of how to use Geolocation API](http://html5demos.com/geo) (source link on page)